# Elasticsearch children-father issue with 'has_parent'

Tags: elasticsearch

Having the following mapping...

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myindex' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "my_parent": {},
    "my_child": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "my_parent" 
}}}}'
```

... the following parent:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/myindex/my_parent/1?pretty=true' -d '{
  "title" : "Microsiervos - Discos duros de 10TB",
  "body" : "Empiezan a sacar DD de 30GB en el mercado"
}'
```

and the following children:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myindex/my_child/2?parent=1' -d '{
  "user": "Pepe"
}'
```

If I do the following `has_child` query:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/my_parent/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query": {
    "has_child": { 
      "type": "my_child",
      "query" : {
           "query_string" : {
               "default_field" : "user",
               "query" : "Pepe"
}}}}}'
```

I get the desired output. `Pepe` is found, and his father is shown:

```
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "myindex",
      "_type" : "my_parent",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{
  "title" : "Microsiervos - En el 69 llegamos a la luna",
  "body" : "Se cumplen 3123 anos de la llegada a la luna"
}
```

But if I try to do it in reverse trying to get the children using `has_parent`:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/my_parent/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": { 
      "parent_type": "my_parent",
      "query" : {
           "query_string" : {
               "default_field" : "body",
               "query" : "mercado"
}}}}}'
```

I dont get any hits. I was supposing to get the `Pepe` children as output. What I'm missing or doing wrong?

PS: I'm using Elasticsearch 2.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake above.You are searching in `my_parent` type. If you want to fetch children using parent, you should fetch it from `child_type`.
Change query to:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/my_child/_search?pretty=true' -d      
'{
"query": {
"has_parent": { 
  "parent_type": "my_parent",
  "query" : {
       "query_string" : {
           "default_field" : "body",
           "query" : "mercado"
      }
    }
  }
 }
}'
```

Please note I have used

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/my_child/_search?pretty=true'
```

instead of

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/my_parent/_search?pretty=true'
```